# SSO on Jboss with RedHat SSO

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, redhat

I have a Library that is use to authenticate my user and get roles. In my library I must call the LDAP, the Database and merge the result to get my user role. Is it possible to call my library with **RH-SSO**? Before I use picketlink and I define in my standalone the login-module to call my lib

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on the upstream project (Keycloak) documentation, you need to implement the [User Storage SPI](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/topics/user-storage.html).

Comment: Thank for the Answer. Do you know if it possible to get role from the external provider and no map in RH-SSO?